# How to generate 10 by 10 matrix for 15 words

Tags: iphone

i am making word search puzzle game.. 
I want to generate around 15 words in 10 * 10 matrix form squres .
each squre be UIButton.
On each button there will be character of word.

words should be arrranged vertically,horizontly,crossed.

How to generate this specific matrix..?

Any one share me the idea or code etc.

Thanks,
Keyur Prajapati

Answer (score 1):

```
Rather than button use uiimageview, it will be easy as u can implement the sliding effect as well.
U need to implement different classes as Matrix, Plate, Coordinate, BoardManager. Now you have implement the logic arround this class. 
.h matrix class 
int row; int column; NSMutableArray *matrix;

.h plate class
Coordinate *currentCordinate; //center coordinate of the plate.
int presentRow; int presentCol;

.h BoardManager
NSInteger boardMatrixRow;  NSInteger boardMatrixColumn;

.h Coordinate
CGFloat x; CGFloat y;

Now implement the methods and apply your logic of inserting the object into matrix array,assign the coordinates to the plates/image, tagging the image.

As such no tutorial encountered.
```